# how to pass js variable to drupal php variable?

Tags: jquery, drupal

I want to pass a js variable to drupal php variable and display its value.
Following is my code.

```
$form['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('titles'),
  '#page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  '#page arguments' => array('test_select'),
  '#access callback' => TRUE,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#prefix' => '<div>',
  '#postfix' => '</div>',
  '#attributes' => array('onchange' => 'test_change')
);

$form['titletext'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'title',
);

drupal_add_js('$('.$form['title']['select'].').change(function () {
  var str ="";
  '.$a.' = "";
  $("'.$form['title']['select'].' option:selected").each(function () {
    str += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
})
.change();', 'inline', 'header');
```

I want to assign that str variable to the textfield value or simply assign that variable to drupal php variable and display it on the page.

Comment: Now i want retrieve the date from the database according to selection in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

I want to pass a js variable to drupal php variable and display its value. ...

use DOM manipulation.. like.. the area you want the result to be displayed do something like

$("select").change(function(){
$("#thevalue").html($(this).val())
})

or in your case.. the each with outputting the text. if you need drupal to get the value.. you gonna have to submit to the back end.. like use ajax etc

Comment: I have wrote $("titletext").change(function(){ $("#title").html($(this).val()) }) but it does not work. titletext is the id of textfield and title is the id of drop down box

Answer (score -1):

i am not know about php but as for textfield concern you can try this..

```
$('#textBoxId').val(str);
```

Comment: I have entered $('#titletext').val(str); but it does not work. the titletext is the id of my textfield. you can see it in above code.

Comment: Now i want retrieve the date from the database according to selection in the drop down list.